# Serverside Datatable search input not filtering

Tags: datatables

I've a datatable loaded with server-side and it works perfectly but the search input is not working properly, as it doesn't search in the table.

Jquery loading table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loanshistory').DataTable( {
          dom: "<'row'<'col-md-4'B><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-4'p>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-md-6'><'col-md-6'>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'i><'col-md-4'p>>",
          buttons: [
               {
                   extend: 'collection',
                   text: '<i class="la la-download"></i> Export',
                   autoClose: true,
                   className: 'btn btn-success btn-icon-sm btn-square dropdown-toggle',
                   buttons: [
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-copy"></i>\xa0\xa0  Copy', extend: 'copyHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>\xa0\xa0  Excel', extend: 'excelHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-csv"></i>\xa0\xa0  CSV', extend: 'csvHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>\xa0\xa0  PDF', extend: 'pdfHtml5'},
                               { text: '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>\xa0\xa0  Print', extend: 'print' }
                            ],
                        fade: true,
               }
          ],
          order: [[ 4, "desc" ]],
          pageLength: 25,
          responsive: true,
          processing: true,
          serverSide: true,
          ajax: "index.php?action=ss-loans-history-get"
      } );
} );
```

ss-loans-history-get file:

```
<?php

$table = 'library_loan';
 
$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
    
    array(
        'db'        => 'copy_id',
        'dt'        => 0,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $result = classLibrary::getCopyByID($d);
            $result1 = $result->fields['code'];
            $result1 = "<code>".$result1."</code> &nbsp;";
            
            $result2 = classLibrary::getBookByID($result->fields["book_id"]);
            if ($result2->fields["subtitle"] != "") {
                $result2 = $result2->fields["title"] . " | " . $result2->fields["subtitle"];
            } else {
                $result2 = $result2->fields["title"];
            }
            $result2 = "<a class='kt-link kt-font-bold' href='./book/".$d."'>".$result2."</a>";
            
            $result = $result1 . $result2;
            
            return $result;
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'centre_id',
        'dt'        => 1,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $result = classLibrary::getCentreByID($d);
            $result = $result->fields["name"];
            return $result;
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'user_id',
        'dt'        => 2,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $result = classUsers::getUserByID($d);
            $result = "<a class='kt-link kt-font-bold' href='./user/".$d."'>".$result->fields["name"] . " " . $result->fields["last_name"] . "</a>";
            return $result;
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'created_at',
        'dt'        => 3,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date("d M, Y",strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'returned_at',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date("d M, Y",strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'id',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $loan = classLibrary::getLoanByID($d);
            
            $resultlent = classLibrary::getStatusByID($loan->fields["status_withdraw_id"]);
            $resultlent = "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--".$resultlent->fields["color"]." kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill kt-badge--rounded'>" . $resultlent->fields["name"] . "</span>";
            
            $resultreturn = classLibrary::getStatusByID($loan->fields["status_return_id"]);
            $resultreturn = "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--".$resultreturn->fields["color"]." kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill kt-badge--rounded'>" . $resultreturn->fields["name"] . "</span>";
            
            $result = $resultlent . " >> " . $resultreturn;
            
            return $result;
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'id',
        'dt'        => 6,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            $result = "<a href='./loan/".$d."' class='btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md' title='View PDF'> <i class='fas fa-file-pdf'></i> </a>";
            return $result;
        }
    ),
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );
 
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll="returned_at is not NULL"  )
);
?>
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped- table-hover" id="loanshistory">
  <thead class="thead-light text-center">
      <tr>
          <th>Book Information</th>
          <th>Centre</th>
          <th>Student</th>
          <th>Lent Date</th>
          <th>Returned Date</th>
          <th>Status<br>Lent >> Return</th>
          <th>View PDF</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tBody">
  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="thead-light text-center">
      <tr>
          <th>Book Information</th>
          <th>Centre</th>
          <th>Student</th>
          <th>Lent Date</th>
          <th>Returned Date</th>
          <th>Status<br>Lent >> Return</th>
          <th>View PDF</th>
      </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I've tried adding searching: true and many things but it isn't working at the moment. Also checked other's questions related to this but can't find a proper answer to fix this issue.

I've got others tables generated by serverside and with same html style and the search input does work in those tables.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Updated code. Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: I've tried removing all HTML markups from the ss-loans-history-get file and leaving as plain text. Also tried reducing data, removing column search jquery code... I've tried many things and I can't get the search input to work... It can search numbers but not strings...  I've also read lots of documentation from datatables.net, but can't find anything to solve this issue...

Comment: A couple of observations, in case they help: (1) Your `initComplete` function builds a select list for the 2nd column (it's not shown in your screenshot, though). The select list values have `^` and `$` added to each value: `'^'+val+'$'`. So that means DataTables passes strings such as `^CBS Language Academy Bollulos$` to the server - for example: `columns[1][search][value]: ^CBS Language Academy Bollulos$`. (2) Also, the `regex` parameter is being set to `true` - so this is being sent to the server: `columns[1][search][regex]: true`. Is this what you want/expect?

Comment: Observation (3) - I am not a PHP person, but I don't see anywhere in your code where you are actually capturing these values and using them to filter your data (because with server-side processing, it up to you to handle all of this logic, not DataTables). Maybe it's there, somewhere.

Comment: @andrewjames (1) I removed the initComplete function in the last version as it wasn't working properly, just updated the code. (2) According to the docs it is set to False by default, so it should escape special characters. (3) Am I supposed to build the search in the server-side php script? I have another table with serverside on and it does the search as normal, I didn't have to build the filters in the php page... I'm quite confused because of this, as the search in the other table works perfectly but not in this one (same class/code/scripts but doesn't work in this one)

Comment: The regex thing - it's just something to be aware of - not a problem. The "server-side table which does not need server-side processing": That is interesting, as I have never seen that. Whenever I use `serverSide: true`, I need to provide all the paging, filtering, sorting logic myself (in a Java servlet, in my case). As the [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/) states: _all actions that DataTables performs (such as paging, searching and ordering) are handed off to a server_. And that is what I have always seen, myself.

Comment: @andrewjames Video of my books datatables code (same as the code here) with the search input working: https://i.gyazo.com/a6e67c36d0ad83905124ebe0f4f2c1a2.mp4 Video of the code here with the search not working: https://i.gyazo.com/d5cd842c6fcc2983856754a52b839114.mp4 You can see that both codes structure is almost identically but in one search works and in the other it doesnt.

Comment: I believe you :-) it's just that I can't explain it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @andrewjames No worries, I'll keep trying to solve it and I'll post the solution when it's fixed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The only other thought I have (well, a guess, really) is that you may be using a framework such as Laravel, with a library such as [Yarja DataTables](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master)... and maybe that library provides integrations with server-side DataTables which I never use. Such integrations may mean you do not have to write _all_ of the server-side sort/filter/page logic yourself.